# jQuery - Select current link only

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I apply the function to the current link only on this menu? If I click on the `Decline` link the function is applied to all links.

I am using this script:

```
$(".js-decline, .js-no").click(function () {
    var declineUser = $('.js-decline-txt');
    var hiding = !declineUser.hasClass('hide');
    if (hiding) {
        $('.js-decline-txt').addClass('hide');
    }

    $(".decline-content").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 400, function () {
        if (!hiding) {
            $('.js-decline-txt').removeClass('hide').css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });

});
```

and this is an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/TX55G/217/)**

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you are using `static approach` to get element by jquery selectors which need to be change in `dynamic manner` by using `$(this)(refer to the element on which event occur at the time)`,
but also you need to `separate both click` because we need to use `$(this)` if we want to element specific and in both case this refer different elements which cause of problem during Dom element search dynamically

```
$(".js-decline").click(function () {
    var declineUser =  $(this).find('.js-decline-txt');

    var hiding = !declineUser.hasClass('hide');
    if (hiding) {
        $(this).find('.js-decline-txt').addClass('hide');
    }

    $(this).next("div.decline-content").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 400, function () {
        if (!hiding) {
            declineUser.removeClass('hide').css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });

});

$(".js-no").click(function () {
       var declineUser =  $(this).parents('li').find('.js-decline-txt');

     var hiding = !declineUser.hasClass('hide');
    if (hiding) {
          $(this).parents('.js-decline-txt').addClass('hide');
    }
    $(this).parents("div.decline-content").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 400, function () {
        if (!hiding) {
            declineUser.removeClass('hide').css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });
```

});

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX55G/225/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the great clarification. That makes more sense now. I'm just starting with jQuery sometimes it's confusing for me but that makes sense now.

Comment: Glad to hear that  from you :)

Answer (score 1):

everything about selector .. you need to use `$(this) , .find()  and .next()`  ..

you can use it like this

```
$(".js-decline, .js-no").click(function () {
    var declineUser = $(this).find('.js-decline-txt');
    var hiding = !declineUser.hasClass('hide');
    if (hiding) {
        declineUser.addClass('hide');
    }

    $(this).next(".decline-content").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 400, function () {
        if (!hiding) {
            declineUser.removeClass('hide').css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/TX55G/219/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TX55G/223/)

```
$(".js-decline, .js-no").click(function () {
    var ClickedLink = $(this); // cache the clicked object
    var declineUser = $('.js-decline-txt');
    var hiding = !declineUser.hasClass('hide');
    if (hiding) {
        ClickedLink.next('.js-decline-txt').addClass('hide'); // refer cached object to find referring objects
    }
    ClickedLink.next(".decline-content").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 400, function () {
        if (!hiding) {
            ClickedLink.removeClass('hide').css('display','inline-block');
        }
    });

});
```

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I thinkg you are looking for this solution

```
$(".js-decline, .js-no").click(function () {
var declineTxt = $(this).closest('.decline-li').find('.js-decline-txt');
var declineContent = $(this).closest('.decline-li').find('.decline-content');

var hiding = !declineTxt.hasClass('hide');
if (hiding) {
   declineTxt.addClass('hide');
}

declineContent.toggle("slide", {
    direction: "left"
}, 400, function () {
    if (!hiding) {
        declineTxt.removeClass('hide').css('display','inline-block');
    }
});
```

});

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tshah0107/bw6aw2wd/)